# How to have many app with one Meteor backend?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor, mobile

I would like to have many mobile app with only one Meteor backend (not only one server) and have some switches inside client code to enable or disable some functionalities.

Until Reloader overwrite any custom setting, how to know which is the current app ?

I tried to:

- Use ***__meteor_runtime_config__.appId*** but Reloader make it uniq
- Use different ***--server*** CNAME pointing to the same backend but Reloader make it uniq
- Have a look inside Package but nothing appear different from an app to another

The only things Reloader don't update are app icon and launchScreen but I don't know if it's possible to access it from client code

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You can do this by building all your apps in one, and then using the login to direct them to the relevant page in your app. Like the Meerkats say: Simple! NGINX Proxy Docker image supports different named servers on one instance.

Comment: Thank Mikkel, unfortunately all apps have different look and feel before logging :(